# Error using drag and drop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel with 07 buttons that can move them left or right without problems using "drag and drop". My problem is that when I put a button on top of an existing one. I put the button where it already existed 43 button 45 and button 43 is below 45 as shown. [image]

This is my code

```
    private void panelAtalhos_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void panelAtalhos_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //create the button - treeview item selected
        Button bt = new Button();
        if (createbutton) // createbutton is a global variable
        {               
            bt.Width = 38;
            bt.Height = 34;
            bt.Top = 2;
            bt.Left = panelAtalhos.Controls.Count * (bt.Width);
            bt.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
            bt.Text = data.ToString("ss");
            bt.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            panelAtalhos.Controls.Add(bt);
            bt.MouseDown += button_MouseDown;
            createbutton = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int resto = (int)(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X / 38);
            ((Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button))).Left = resto * 38;  
        }                                                
    }

    private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).DoDragDrop(sender as Button, DragDropEffects.Move);
        criarbotao = false;
    }
```

What is missing in the code?

Comment: Should your code use `DragDropEffects.Copy instead of .Move`.. have you stepped thru the code to see if something is not happening the way that you are expecting..?

Comment: DJ KRAZE, 
I changed the code and put "Copy" but I can not drag them. My problem is when you have a button in a certain place and I put another button in this place. Then one of the buttons is hidden (under the other).

Comment: is there a way to bring that button to foreground also what do you expect to happen with the button that's covered or that you're trying to move over..? should it go to the previous buttons Indexed position..? if so then you need to capture that index

Comment: there is no code there to test if another button is already in that spot. and act accordingly

Comment: How to know if a button exists in a certain place? Maybe it's a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int resto = (int)(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X / 38);
```

You have two problems.  One is the Z-order, the other is this statement.  It is not correct, you must map the *absolute* cursor position to the *relative* position for the button.  Relative from the client area of its parent, the panel.  Right now you're sending it off into the weeds, too far to the right.  Easily far enough that it won't be visible anymore.  Code ought to resemble:

```
  var btn = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button));
  var pos = btn.Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
  btn.Left = (pos.X / 38) * 38;
  btn.BringToFront();
```